# What is the reliability of UDP multicast on a LAN?

Tags: networking, udp, multicast

Let's say that all receivers are connected to the same router, which is one hop away. What percent of UDP multicast packets should I expect to be dropped/lost in this setup?

Comment: What other traffic is going through the network?

Comment: Other traffic: Several thousand HTTP requests per second to each individual server. (Clustered HTTP servers with multicast being used to coordinate servers in the cluster)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most packets are lost due to buffer overflows not due to the quality of the network, aside of using interference prone mediums such as radio.

So to answer, you should expect 0% dropped packets.  What you will see is entirely dependent upon application load causing the incoming socket buffers to not be timely read.